# Save caption in a box

Tags: captions, boxes, size

I want to measure the height of a caption, by typesetting into a `\savebox`, but run into

> You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.

The offending line in the MWE below is commented out.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\CaptionSavebox}
\captionsetup{width=0.20\linewidth}%

\newcommand*{\CaptionText}{This is a caption for the above figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    %\savebox{\CaptionSavebox}{\captionof{figure}{\CaptionText}}% <--- Why can't I do this?
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \usebox{\CaptionSavebox}%
    \captionof{figure}{\CaptionText}% <-- don't need this if have the caption in the savebox
    \label{fig: figure label}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that since `\savebox` puts the contents in an `\hbox` the problem is that the caption can be more than one line. You can fix it by putting it in a `\parbox`.

There comes an extra empty line below the caption in the box. It seems like it is produced by `\caption` to ensure it is placed on a line of its own. Below I have removed that line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\CaptionSavebox}
\captionsetup{width=0.20\linewidth}%

\newcommand*{\CaptionText}{This is a caption for the above figure}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
    %\savebox{\CaptionSavebox}{\captionof{figure}{\CaptionText}}% <--- Why can't I do this?
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    %%
    \savebox{\CaptionSavebox}{\parbox[b]{\captionwidth}{\caption{\CaptionText}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}}
    \par
    \usebox{\CaptionSavebox}%
    \rlap{\rule{0.5pt}{\ht\CaptionSavebox} Height=\the\ht\CaptionSavebox Depth=\the\dp\CaptionSavebox}
    %%\captionof{figure}{\CaptionText}% <-- don't need this if have the caption in the savebox
    \label{fig: figure label}%
\end{figure}%

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` that you added is trying to adjust for the `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`. If you set `\abovecaptionskip=0pt` and `\belowcaptionskip=0pt` you can see that you get the correct height without the `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`.